# Any alternatives to Jackknife estimate for acceleration constant a in BCa bootstrap CI

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, discrete-distributions, jackknife

I am trying to implement the bias-corrected and accelerated (BCa) bootstrap confidence interval (CI) for parameters from discrete distributions. The way to compute the acceleration constant "a" is to use a jackknife estimate (leave one out). However, I cannot find any other options.

As far as I know, the jackknife estimate is valid for the smooth statistic. For the nonsmoothed statistic, an alternative is to use a delete-d jackknife instead of a usual delete-1 jackknife, which works for the median. However, it doesn't work in my case.

I also checked the positive jackknife (I am not sure if it's valid for the nonsmoothed statistic). It works in my case, at least in my dataset, but it can be a severe underestimate of the variance according to Hinkley (1978). I haven't checked the behavior of the infinitesimal jackknife since the procedure seems complicated.

I searched a lot but cannot find appropriate literature. Can anyone give me some hints or relevant literature that might help? Many thanks!